# Measuring Download, Upload and Ping

Tags: performance, network-speed

I'm trying a lot to measure download,upload and ping(Packets sent,received and lost) via browser between a wireless client and my freeBSD Server.

I tried NodeJS, I came up with a solution, but the client needs to manually upload a computer file, and this isn't the best solution.

With the php's files I found around the web I couldn't measure up/down when the connection was above 10mbps, and when the wireless client was losing packets the php couldn't handle the test.

Someone knows a better solution than manually doing this test?

Answer (score 1):

Use [iperf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf/).  You can configure the server to listen on a port, the connect with the client to do upload and download testing.  It'll provide great statistics on throughput.

For checking the round-trip time between the hosts, good ol' ping should suffice.

Comment: But I need to do this inside the browser